# CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file couldn't be found while generating UWP Packages using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, windows-runtime, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm following this [blog](http://prac-code.blogspot.com/2016/03/uwp-continuous-integration-of-uwpor.html) to automate generating app packages using Jenkins for Windows 10 apps. Later I will be using the same for Windows 8.1 apps too. But I'm stuck while building the packages and gives the following error in the Jenkins console.

FYI: I can generate packages normally from Visual Studio.

In Jenkins my Windows batch command is:

> C:\Users\PC-Name\.nuget\nuget\nuget.exe restore
>   "C:\Users\PC-Name\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.sln" -ConfigFile
>   "C:\Users\PC-Name\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config" -NoCache

And Windows Powershell command is:

> $msbuild = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"
>
> set-alias msbuild $msbuild
>
> $sln_name = "C:\Users\PC-Name\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.sln"
>
> $vs_config = "Release"
>
> $vs_platfom = "ARM"
>
> Write-Host "Building solution`n" -foregroundcolor
>   Green
>
> msbuild $sln_name /t:Build /p:Configuration=$vs_config
>   /p:Platform=$vs_platfom /v:q /nologo

Following is the error in the console:

```
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.CSharp\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\Microsoft.CSharp.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.VisualBasic\10.0.0\ref\netcore50\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\mscorlib.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.AppContext\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.AppContext.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Collections.Concurrent\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Collections\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Collections.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Collections.Immutable\1.1.37\lib\dotnet\System.Collections.Immutable.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Collections.NonGeneric\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Collections.Specialized\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Collections.Specialized.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ComponentModel.Annotations\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ComponentModel\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ComponentModel.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Core.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Data.Common\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Data.Common.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Contracts\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Debug\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tools\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\4.0.20\ref\dotnet\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Dynamic.Runtime\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Globalization.Calendars\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Globalization\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Globalization.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Globalization.Extensions\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO.Compression\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.IO.Compression.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.IO.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO.FileSystem\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.IO.FileSystem.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO.IsolatedStorage\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Linq\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Linq.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Linq.Expressions\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Linq.Expressions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Linq.Parallel\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Linq.Parallel.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Linq.Queryable\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Linq.Queryable.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.Http\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.Http.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.Http.Rtc\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.Http.Rtc.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.NetworkInformation\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.Primitives\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Net.Primitives.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.Requests\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Net.Requests.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.Sockets\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Net.Sockets.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Numerics.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors\4.1.0\ref\dotnet\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.WindowsRuntime\4.0.0\lib\dotnet\System.Numerics.Vectors.WindowsRuntime.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ObjectModel\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.ObjectModel.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection.Context\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Reflection.Context.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Reflection.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection.Extensions\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection.Metadata\1.0.22\lib\dotnet\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection.Primitives\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Resources.ResourceManager\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime\4.0.20\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Handles\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.Handles.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices\4.0.20\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Numerics\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json\4.0.1\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives\4.1.0\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml\4.1.0\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime\4.0.10\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Security.Claims\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Security.Claims.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Security.Principal\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Security.Principal.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.Duplex\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.Http\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.Primitives\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.ServiceModel.Security\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Text.Encoding\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Text.Encoding.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Text.RegularExpressions\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Threading\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Threading.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Overlapped\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow\4.5.25\lib\dotnet\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Tasks\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Threading.Tasks.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Threading.Timer\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Threading.Timer.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Windows.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Xml.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Xml.Linq.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility\1.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Xml.Serialization.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Xml.XDocument\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Xml.XDocument.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Xml.XmlDocument\4.0.0\ref\dotnet\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\System.Xml.XmlSerializer\4.0.10\ref\dotnet\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll' could not be found [C:\Users\ITH-143\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin\JenkinsWin.csproj]
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Visual Studio Version:**
*Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
Installed Version: Enterprise*

Target: Universal Windows

Target Version:Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586)

Min Version: Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)

Answer (score 0):

Same error there, i read somewhere that it's relater to the MSBuild executable that is executed under local system privilege, can you try under admin privileges ?

Comment: I just tested right now, installed Jenkins on local and got same problem, i changed Jenkins privilege and launched the build -> Succeded.

Comment: How to do admin privileges?

Comment: mine was not an admin issue, the files were missing, i would recommend installing the dotnet plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9190?pr=teamcity then run 'dotnet restore' before your project